# Magmi alternative for Magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, importexport, magmi

It's been 4 days already that I'm digging the internet for Magmi alternative for Magento 2.0, since Magmi doesn't have any Magento 2.0 compatible version (or I'm unable to find it).

if anyone of you have experience working with a module or tool in Magento 2.0 for importing/exporting Category and product, could you please share it with me? thank you

take in to consideration that I've already tried using Firebear.

Comment: Same question here...

Answer (score 4):

You can always try the native import/export interface. 
Tools like Magmi (directly writing sql) will suffer in the long run, because import not imports a bit differently (repository->save() instead of direct sql as it was before) and because of the newly introduced interceptors it will be hard to build a sql-data-pump that will not break with 3rd party data-handling.

Comment: native import export interface takes about 2-3 hours to import just 2000 products into magento. It also don't have anything for category import or other kind of imports. This is why she is looking for an alternative for Magmi. Me too!

Comment: I did get the problems. I just tried to clarify why there is no replacement as of now and why it will be hard to have something available if data-integrity is your main concern.

There is a wrapper for the format (firegento_fastsimpleimport2) but we did not add any functionality as we did in m2 with avs_fastsimpleimport simply because of time constraints.

Comment: @MichelGokan, are you speaking from experience with Magento 2? They made significant improvements in importer performance as a point of focus.

Comment: Personally I was trying to import around 2400 product to Magento 2.0, with the Magento 2.0 native import, and it took more 3 hours. so eventually I had to stop it and look for a better solution.

Comment: Wow that is kinda slow.
My experience is more that 1k skus took not longer than minutes.
Do you have many images or cross-product-relations (configurable/bundle/grouped/related/crosssell/upsell)? Those slowed me down considerably. And by far the most important: did you use php7?

Comment: Yes I had all sorts of products, all of them have images and yes I use php 7.0.0

Answer (score 3):

Searching around I came across this:
https://github.com/tagesjump/magmi-m2

There is also some talk related to some issues on this issue:
https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/369

I hope this will help somebody.

NOTE: This was not tested and I do not know if it works or not.

Answer (score 3):

Here is most alive recent project which have merged few another attempts to port Magmi for Magento 2 - https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-git

Another interesting project is M2IF - Magento 2 Import Framework -
https://github.com/techdivision/import

*The objective of M2IF is to provide a fully functional replacement for the Magento 2 standard import functionality with a 100 % CSV file compatibility. In contrast to other approaches, the framework is not build as a Magento 2 extension, although it has no dependencies to other frameworks like Symfony, Laravel or others. Instead, it provides independent components, that can be tied together as needed, by adding them as composer dependency.*

We also have implemented all core Magmi features for Magento 2 on our commercial extension (400$) [Improved Import](https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to switch to PimGento format and extension.
Probably add few more queries to move images to right order.

Originally designed for Akeneo data import, provides decent performance and flexibility.

It uses Mysql CSV file load.

P.S. Yoav Kutner supports Akeneo development, which is good sign.